# Is there a before_save_post hook or something similar

Tags: hooks, post-status, wp-update-post

I need to check the value of a post status before is changed during a post update or even bulk update. And then depending on that value, adjust other values of the post

**Example:**

Lets say I have a custom post status

- status-one
- status-two
- status-three

I have post "A" who's status is **status-one**. 
So when I update this post to another status, **status-two**, I need to check if my old status was **status-one** or not?

I know this sounds a bit confusing. Please do let me know if there is any way I can clarify it.

Comment: So you need to update the post if its status is **status-one** otherwise it will not be updated, right ?

Comment: @the_dramatist , I need the to run a function if post status has been switched form status-one to status-two. However, if the post status has been changed from status-three to status-one, I don't need to run that function

Comment: I'm not clear, so you just need to know the previous status only ?

Comment: @the_dramatist Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hook called [`transition_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/) which runs at every transition. You have both the old and new status available inside the hook.

Comment: Thank you @cjbj. This is exactly what I was looking for :)